# Representation integral for some branch of arcsin(w)?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G:=\mathbb{C}-\lbrace t\in \mathbb{R}\vert$ $\vert t\vert\geq1\rbrace$. Shows there is a representation for all $w\in G$
$$\arcsin(w)=\int_{\gamma(w)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}d\zeta$$ 
$\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}$ take the branch of root such that  $(1-\zeta^{2})$ on $G$ assumes the value 1 on $\zeta=0$ an $\gamma(w)$ is an integration path form 0 to w on $G$.

I don't know what it means, simply shows that represntation is well defined or the formula $\arcsin(w)=\frac{1}{i}\mathrm{Log}(iw+\sqrt{1-w^{2}})$ and the representation integral are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the only singularities of
$$
\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-z}+\frac1{1+z}\right)\tag{1}
$$
are at $z=1$ and $z=-1$. If $\gamma$ is any closed path that does not circle these singularities, then by [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)
$$
\int_\gamma\frac1{1-z^2}\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{2}
$$
No path in $G$ can circle either singularity.

Since the difference of two paths between $0$ and $\zeta$ is a closed path, if both paths are in $G$, the difference of the integrals along those paths is $0$. That is, the function
$$
\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)=\int_0^\zeta\frac1{1-z^2}\mathrm{d}z\tag{3}
$$
is well-defined (it doesn't matter what path in $G$ is taken).

Exponentiating $(3)$ gives us a well-defined function
$$
\frac1{1+\zeta}\exp\left(\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\tag{4}
$$
which has no poles in $G$. Since $G$ is simply connected and there are no singularities of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}$ in $G$, we get a well-defined
$$
\arcsin(w)=\int_0^w\frac1{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\mathrm{d}\zeta\tag{5}
$$

Comment: why does this follows $\frac1{1+\zeta}\exp\left(\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}$

Comment: @Porufes: Since we have a well-defined $\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)$, we exponentiate to get $\exp\left(\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}}$ then divide by $1+\zeta$.

Comment: oh and then you say that $\frac{1}{i}\mathrm{Log}(iw+\sqrt{1-w^{2}}) = \int_0^w \frac1{1+\zeta}\exp\left(\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}\zeta $ ??

Comment: @Porufes: The integral is well defined. There are two functions that are not well-defined on $\mathbb{C}$ in $\frac1i\color{#C00000}{\log}\left(iw+\color{#C00000}{ \sqrt{\color{#000000}{1-w^2}}}\right)$: $\log(z)$ and $\sqrt{z}$. How are they supposed to be defined?

Comment: I need to fix the branch were that make sense?

Comment: @Porufes: You need to define what you mean by $\log(z)$ and $\sqrt{z}$ in that function. Using my answer, you can define $\sqrt{1-w^2}$. The fact that there is no solution to $iw+\sqrt{1-w^2}=0$ also helps to show that its log can be well-defined.

Comment: The hypothesis $\arcsin:G\rightarrow G'$ where $G'=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}\vert-\pi/2<Re(z)<-\pi/2\rbrace$ is biholomorphic, make sense the formula $$\arcsin(w)=\frac{1}{i}\mathrm{Log}(iw+\sqrt{1-w^{2}})$$
Then, the integral representation and this formula must be equivalent.

Comment: @Donyarley: the problem with simply defining arcsin that way is that neither $\log(z)$ nor $\sqrt{z}$ are well-defined on $\mathbb{C}$. The whole idea is to show that with the proper branch cuts, each definition leads to a well-defined on a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.